# Adding values of checked radio boxes in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javaScript and am confused on how I should get the total from the checked radio boxes. Also I am trying to add a submit button for the user, so that the total will only be revealed after they click submit. I feel as though I may not be parsing the values properly?

Appreciate the help
Thanks!

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  function calculateTotal() {
    var score = 0;

   q1 = new Array(1,2,3,4,5);
   q2 = new Array(1,2,3,4,5);
   q3 = new Array(1,2,3,4,5);
   q4 = new Array(1,2,3,4,5);
   q5 = new Array(1,2,3,4,5);

   for (var i = 0; i < q1.length; i++ ) {
     if(q1[i].checked){
       score += parseFloat(q1[i].value);
     }

  for(var c = 0; c < q2.length; c++){
    if(q2[i].checked){
      score += parseFloat(q2[i].value);
    }

    for(var c = 0; c < q3.length; c++){
      if(q3[i].checked){
        score += parseFloat(q3[i].value);
      }

      for(var c = 0; c < q4.length; c++){
        if(q4[i].checked){
          score += parseFloat(q4[i].value);
        }

      for(var c = 0; c < q5.length; c++){
          if(q5[i].checked){
            score += parseFloat(q5[i].value);
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}

  </script>
</head>

<p class="question">1. Rate your family life?</p>

<ul class="answers">
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">1</label>
  <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">2</label>
  <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">3</label>
  <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d"><label for="q1d">4</label>
  <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="e" id="q1e"><label for="q1e">5</label>
  <br/>
</ul>


<p class="question">2. Rate your romantic life?</p>

<ul class="answers">
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a"><label for="q2a">1</label>
  <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b"><label for="q2b">2</label>
    <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c"><label for="q2c">3</label>
    <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" id="q2d"><label for="q2d">4</label>
    <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="e" id="q2e"><label for="q2e">5</label>
      <br/>
</ul>

<p class="question">3. Rate your social life?</p>

<ul class="answers">
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" id="q3a"><label for="q3a">1</label>
   <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" id="q3b"><label for="q3b">2</label>
  <br/>
 <input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" id="q3c"><label for="q3c">3</label>
  <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="d" id="q3d"><label for="q3d">4</label>
  <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="e" id="q3e"><label for="q3e">5</label>
   <br/>
</ul>

<p class="question">4. Rate your career/academic life?</p>

<ul class="answers">
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="a" id="q4a"><label for="q4a">1</label>
    <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="b" id="q4b"><label for="q4b">2</label>
    <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="c" id="q4c"><label for="q4c">3</label>
   <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="d" id="q4d"><label for="q4d">4</label>
   <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="e" id="q4e"><label for="q4e">5</label>
  <br/>
</ul>

<p class="question">5. Rate how you physically feel (e.g. lethargic 1 to 
energetic 5)?</p>

<ul class="answers">
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="a" id="q5a"><label for="q5a">1</label>
    <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="b" id="q5b"><label for="q5b">2</label>
   <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="c" id="q5c"><label for="q5c">3</label>
   <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="d" id="q5d"><label for="q5d">4</label>
   <br/>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="d" id="q5e"><label for="q5e">5</label>
  <br/>
</ul>

 <script>
alert("Your overall score is " + calculateTotal());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to get your checkboxes as arrays, not create some unrelated arrays yourself. That can be done using `document.getElementsByName("q1");`

```
function calculateTotal() {
        var score = 0;

       q1 = document.getElementsByName("q1");
       q2 = document.getElementsByName("q2");
       q3 = document.getElementsByName("q3");
       q4 = document.getElementsByName("q4");
       q5 = document.getElementsByName("q5");

       for (var i = 0; i < q1.length; i++ ) {
         if(q1[i].checked){
           score += parseFloat(q1[i].value);
         }

      for(var c = 0; c < q2.length; c++){
        if(q2[i].checked){
          score += parseFloat(q2[i].value);
        }

        for(var c = 0; c < q3.length; c++){
          if(q3[i].checked){
            score += parseFloat(q3[i].value);
          }

          for(var c = 0; c < q4.length; c++){
            if(q4[i].checked){
              score += parseFloat(q4[i].value);
            }

          for(var c = 0; c < q5.length; c++){
              if(q5[i].checked){
                score += parseFloat(q5[i].value);
              }

            }
          }
        }
      }
     }
    }
```

EDIT: Oh, and for the button to calculate the checked values by the user, you can do really easy something like:

```
<div onClick="calculateTotal();"> Calculate total </div>
```

Comment: Hi Catalin, thanks for your reply! I've added the changes to the code but for some reason, when I press submit, nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

You add a button, attach an event handler to that button, and calculate the total

```js
document.getElementById('total').addEventListener('click', calculateTotal);

function calculateTotal() {
  var els = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name^=q]:checked');
  var val = [].map.call(els, function(el) {
    return "abcde".split('').indexOf(el.value) + 1;
  });
  var tot = val.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b
  });

  alert(tot);
}
```

```html
<p class="question">1. Rate your family life?</p>

<ul class="answers">
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">1</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">2</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">3</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d"><label for="q1d">4</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="e" id="q1e"><label for="q1e">5</label>
  <br/>
</ul>


<p class="question">2. Rate your romantic life?</p>

<ul class="answers">
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a"><label for="q2a">1</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b"><label for="q2b">2</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c"><label for="q2c">3</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" id="q2d"><label for="q2d">4</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="e" id="q2e"><label for="q2e">5</label>
  <br/>
</ul>

<p class="question">3. Rate your social life?</p>

<ul class="answers">
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" id="q3a"><label for="q3a">1</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" id="q3b"><label for="q3b">2</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" id="q3c"><label for="q3c">3</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="d" id="q3d"><label for="q3d">4</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q3" value="e" id="q3e"><label for="q3e">5</label>
  <br/>
</ul>

<p class="question">4. Rate your career/academic life?</p>

<ul class="answers">
  <input type="radio" name="q4" value="a" id="q4a"><label for="q4a">1</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q4" value="b" id="q4b"><label for="q4b">2</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q4" value="c" id="q4c"><label for="q4c">3</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q4" value="d" id="q4d"><label for="q4d">4</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q4" value="e" id="q4e"><label for="q4e">5</label>
  <br/>
</ul>

<p class="question">5. Rate how you physically feel (e.g. lethargic 1 to energetic 5)?</p>

<ul class="answers">
  <input type="radio" name="q5" value="a" id="q5a"><label for="q5a">1</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q5" value="b" id="q5b"><label for="q5b">2</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q5" value="c" id="q5c"><label for="q5c">3</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q5" value="d" id="q5d"><label for="q5d">4</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q5" value="d" id="q5e"><label for="q5e">5</label>
  <br/>
</ul>

<button id="total">Total</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. You will want to change the value="" to the value you want to add. the document.getElementsByNames("").value will get this value. Also your for loops are all nested which you don't want to do.
You can add a button with an onclick method to call the method you want. since all the values have the same length you can get away with just one for loop. You also probably want to add a  tag for your html body.

```
function calculateTotal() {
        var score = 0;

        q1 = document.getElementsByName("q1");
        q2 = document.getElementsByName("q2");
        q3 = document.getElementsByName("q3");
        q4 = document.getElementsByName("q4");
        q5 = document.getElementsByName("q5");

        for (var i = 0; i < q1.length; i++) {
            if (q1[i].checked) {
                score += parseFloat(q1[i].value);
            }

            if (q2[i].checked) {
                score += parseFloat(q2[i].value);
            }


            if (q3[i].checked) {
                score += parseFloat(q3[i].value);
            }


            if (q4[i].checked) {
                score += parseFloat(q4[i].value);
            }


            if (q5[i].checked) {
                score += parseFloat(q5[i].value);
            }
        }
        return score;
    }
```

Here is what one of the radio buttons should look like. 

    1. Rate your family life?

```
<ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">1</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">2</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="3" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">3</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="4" id="q1d"><label for="q1d">4</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" id="q1e"><label for="q1e">5</label>
    <br/>
</ul>


<p class="question">2. Rate your romantic life?</p>

<ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" id="q2a"><label for="q2a">1</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="2" id="q2b"><label for="q2b">2</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="3" id="q2c"><label for="q2c">3</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="4" id="q2d"><label for="q2d">4</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="5" id="q2e"><label for="q2e">5</label>
    <br/>
</ul>

<p class="question">3. Rate your social life?</p>

<ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" id="q3a"><label for="q3a">1</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="2" id="q3b"><label for="q3b">2</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="3" id="q3c"><label for="q3c">3</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="4" id="q3d"><label for="q3d">4</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="5" id="q3e"><label for="q3e">5</label>
    <br/>
</ul>

<p class="question">4. Rate your career/academic life?</p>

<ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="q4" value="1" id="q4a"><label for="q4a">1</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2" id="q4b"><label for="q4b">2</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q4" value="3" id="q4c"><label for="q4c">3</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q4" value="4" id="q4d"><label for="q4d">4</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q4" value="5" id="q4e"><label for="q4e">5</label>
    <br/>
</ul>

<p class="question">5. Rate how you physically feel (e.g. lethargic 1 to energetic 5)?</p>

<ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="q5" value="1" id="q5a"><label for="q5a">1</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q5" value="2" id="q5b"><label for="q5b">2</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q5" value="3" id="q5c"><label for="q5c">3</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q5" value="4" id="q5d"><label for="q5d">4</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q5" value="5" id="q5e"><label for="q5e">5</label>
    <br/>
</ul>

<button type="submit" onclick="alert(calculateTotal())">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason your provided code didn't work was because you forgot to return the calculated score from your function:

```
function calculateScore() {
   // your code...
   return score;
}
```

You also need to make sure each of your loops is closed, with a curly brace, before starting the next one.

However, the most readable way to get the value of a group of radio boxes is to use a form element like so:

```js
function calculateScore() {
  var formElement = document.getElementById("the-form"),
      score = 0;
  score += parseInt(formElement.q1.value);
  score += parseInt(formElement.q2.value);
  return score;
}

function displayScore() {
 document.getElementById("the-score").innerText = calculateScore();
}
```

```html
<form id="the-form">

<input type="radio" name="q1" value=1 id="q1-a1"><label for="q1-a1">1</label>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value=2 id="q1-a2"><label for="q1-a2">2</label>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value=3 id="q1-a3"><label for="q1-a3">3</label>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value=4 id="q1-a4"><label for="q1-a4">4</label>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value=5 id="q1-a5"><label for="q1-a5">5</label>
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value=1 id="q2-a1"><label for="q2-a1">1</label>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value=2 id="q2-a2"><label for="q2-a2">2</label>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value=3 id="q2-a3"><label for="q2-a3">3</label>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value=4 id="q2-a4"><label for="q2-a4">4</label>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value=5 id="q2-a5"><label for="q2-a5">5</label>

</form>

<button onclick="displayScore()">Calculate Score</button>
<br>
<output id="the-score"></output>
```

The form element contains properties named after the `name` tags of each of the inputs within the form and their values can be accessed with the `value` property.

By changing the values from a..e to 1..5 the code can be simpler.